# SQL - Selecting various counts

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following tables:

```
User
-------------------
id BIGINT
name text

Session
-------------------
id BIGINT
username text
last_login datetime
```

And  want to get the total user count, AND the count of users which have a session with a last login from today. How can i model the query?

Comment: Have user_id column instead of username in Session table.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I did not design those tables, and i can't modify them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that you fix the session table to have `userId` rather than `userName`.  Then your answer depends on the database.  The general idea is something like this:

```
select count(distinct u.id) as user_count,  -- including those with no sessions
       sum(case when cast(last_login as date) = CURRENT_DATE
from users u left join
     sessions s
     on u.id = s.userId ;
```

This is the sketch of the logic.  Removing the time component from a date/time values varies by database.  The way of representing the current date varies by database.